# Derivation of $\text{A} \vee \neg{\text{A}}$ without a premise.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In one of my homework problems, I need to deduce that $\text{A} \vee \neg{\text{A}}$ without a premise.

The lecturer mentioned that students should "combine" answers for the previous two problems with some editing.

The previous two problems were to prove $\neg\left(\text{A} \vee \neg{\text{A}}\right) \vdash \neg\text{A}$ and $\neg\left(\text{A} \vee \neg{\text{A}}\right) \vdash \text{A}$.

This is what I did for both:

[image]

[image]

Also, for these problems, the lecturer gave a derivation format with a certain number of lines like this:
[image]

For combining these two, I was thinking I need an $\vee$-elimination to somehow get $\text{A} \vee \neg\text{A}$. When I combine these two for the original problem, I get this:

[image]

But I feel like I would need to more lines stating $\text{A} \vee \neg\text{A}$ after lines 5 and 9.

Comment: 1)-5) is right. Now, from 5) jump directly to 7) and use the new contradiction to derive 10) from 1).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA The thing is that I need to strictly use the format given. If I jump from line 5 to 7, I don't get 10 lines in total :(

Comment: See the answer to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2054315/proving-law-of-excluded-middle-in-fitch-system)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules of negation elimination and negation introduction *in your proof system* requires the derivation of two contradictions within the context of the assumption.    Now, the assumption and its own contradiction would suffice, but it is only necessary to derive *any* two contradictory statements.

$$\begin{array}{|l}~~~~\begin{array}{|l} \neg P\\\hline~~\vdots\\~~ Q\\~~\vdots\\\neg Q\end{array}\\~~P\end{array}\qquad\begin{array}{|l}~~~~\begin{array}{|l} ~~ P\\\hline~~\vdots\\~~ Q\\~~\vdots\\\neg Q\end{array}\\\neg P\end{array}$$

So your proof is quite okay as it stands.

---

$$\begin{array}{|l}~~~~\begin{array}{|l}~~1.~\neg (A\vee\neg A)\\\hline~~\begin{array}{|l}~~2.~A\\\hline~~3.~ A\vee\neg A\hspace{10ex}{\vee}\mathrm I~2\\~~4.~\neg(A\vee\neg A)\hspace{7ex}\mathrm R~1\end{array}\\~~5.~\neg A\hspace{17ex}{\neg}\mathsf I~2{-}4\\~~\begin{array}{|l}~~6.~\neg A\\\hline~~7.~ A\vee\neg A\hspace{10ex}{\vee}\mathrm I~6\\~~8.~\neg(A\vee\neg A)\hspace{7ex}\mathrm R~1\end{array}\\~~9.~~~ A\hspace{17ex}{\neg}\mathsf E~6{-}8\end{array}\\10.~A\vee\neg A\hspace{15.5ex}{\neg}\mathsf E~1{-}9\end{array}$$

Now, since that is the skeleton you were required to fill, you **have done what was asked**.

---

Of course, there *are* other skeletons and the standard proof prunes things down just a bit.

$$\begin{array}{|l}~~~~\begin{array}{|l}~~1.~\neg (A\vee\neg A)\\\hline~~\begin{array}{|l}~~2.~A\\\hline~~3.~ A\vee\neg A\hspace{10ex}{\vee}\mathrm I~2\\~~4.~\neg(A\vee\neg A)\hspace{7ex}\mathrm R~1\end{array}\\~~5.~\neg A\hspace{17ex}{\neg}\mathsf I~2{-}4\\~~6.~ A\vee\neg A\hspace{12ex}{\vee}\mathrm I~5\end{array}\\~~7.~A\vee\neg A\hspace{15.5ex}{\neg}\mathsf E~1{-}6\end{array}$$